# Is there a way to get kitchen to use the Vagrantfile?

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to use kitchen to automate testing of chef recipes and of vagrant environments, but when I run kitchen it ignores the Vagrantfile that is present and does everything based on the .kitchen.yml file. I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to tell kitchen to use the Vagrantfile in setting up the vagrant vm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass a Vagrantfile template to it [like this](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant#-vagrantfile_erb). See the [default template](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/blob/master/templates/Vagrantfile.erb) for an example.

The idea anyway is to normally configure everything via .kitchen.yml (and .kitchen.local.yml).  They are also rendered with Erb, so you can even add ruby logic into them.

Comment: Thank you for this! Following your links let to better documentation than docs.chef.io has. Learned items under `vagrantfiles` array must end in `.rb`. Solved my problem!